# Is it possible to see the entries in a Core Data table non-programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, core-data

I've been looking into some tutorials on using Core Data, and I've seen consists of setting up the Entities and Attributes for Core Data in *.xcdatamodeld, then actually working with the data itself through a view on the app using `NSManagedObjectContext` and all the related coding.

I'm wondering if there is a way to see the data (from within Xcode) without having to build up a whole view to do it?  I was looking through the Apple docs quick and everything there also just seems to have all the code for accessing the data, but I didn't see anything that suggests just looking at the tables is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an SQL app and inspect the database.

Comment: Yeah, I knew you could do it that way, I was more asking about if there was a way to from Xcode itself.  Sorry I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to inspect the content of a Core Data database except with code or an SQL inspector app.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Xcode's organizer, select the devices tab, select the device you are using, click on "Application" tab, and download the data of the application you are trying to see the data from. You can find the .sqlite file and see the data yourself.